# have multiple columns need to display column type with other column in rows

Tags: sql

input
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuUeo.jpg)

output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qifre.jpg)

select deptno, replace(title,'d','author),date from employee

for the particular departno I have multiple title and date so i want to display in row wise example

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Only tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: Are the columns called "table1" etc? And is the rest data? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @JelmerJellema  exactly ... well i have 4 columns in that column1 i have a value 1 : for that value I want to display other value of the type displayed in a column in row wise

Comment: Sorry, I really cannot understand it. Do you have an SQL export or something of these tables?

Comment: @JelmerJellema added some images might help to get it

Comment: Not really. I don't see the value 'five' in the input.

What I _think_ you want to do is:
For all rows with the same value in column X, combine the values of column Y in one output column.

Comment: @JelmerJellema ok added five ... well that is the sql query i have the input and I want the output as shown

Comment: could you please give us the plain sql for the table definitions, an sql export for the data and the sql engine you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data does not match your desired results. Here is what I believe you want:

```
create table deleteme_tbl(department int, title varchar2(20), mydate date);
insert into deleteme_tbl values( 1,'One', date '2016-01-01');
insert into deleteme_tbl values( 1,'Two', date '2016-04-01');
insert into deleteme_tbl values( 1,'three', date '2016-02-02');
insert into deleteme_tbl values( 2,'five', date '2016-04-04');
insert into deleteme_tbl values( 2,'six', null);
insert into deleteme_tbl values( 2,'seven', null);
commit;

  SELECT department
       , LISTAGG (title, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY title) titles
       , LISTAGG (mydate, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY mydate) mydates
    FROM deleteme_tbl
GROUP BY department;

DEPARTMENT TITLES         MYDATES
1          One,Two,three  01-JAN-16,02-FEB-16,01-APR-16
2          five,seven,six 04-APR-16
```